# Good TV tuner and remote for HTPC

Tags: htpc, television-tuner

Not a huge question, I just was wondering if there were any pointers on what to look for and where to get a TV Tuner and a Remote (not necessarily a combo) when building an RPi-based HTPC. Answers regarding good products in general for the making of an RPi-based HTPC are also great here.

It's a project I've looked into somewhat, but I have very little idea what I am looking for in terms of the equipment that makes it behave like a real Home Theater, complete with IR remote and TV Tuner.

I know of this IR remote/reciever from Adafruit: [link](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1560), but it looks a little cheap, so I wasn't sure if that was something to go ahead with, or if I should look elsewhere.

Comment: I just use my iPhone...It is something I have on me all the time...handy and easy to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a USB TV tuner like [this](http://sundtek.com/shop/Nach-Marke/Hersteller/Sundtek-Devices/Sundtek-MediaTV-Pro-III-DVB-C/T/T2-FM-Radio-AnalogTV.html). In combination with XBMC.

For the remote you can you the logitech harmony with an IR dongle, like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00224ZDFY)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking onto this also. I found this: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=CEC

Enjoy!

Comment: Could you please try to be a little more verbose and explain why this deserves your recommendation?

Answer (score -2):

I recommend this universal IR USB dongle: https://flirc.tv/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please try to be a little more verbose and explain why this deserves your recommendation?

Comment: Well, I guess you've got a point. Matter of fact, in the review queue where your new answer popped up, I did not see or check the old answers and that they show the same issue. Which is why I only gave you that hint right now. [One-line-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156941/one-line-answers) are not a problem per se but always worth a try to be expanded. (And yes, same thing applies to the answers above).

Comment: While I agree with @Ghanima that this answer is a bit short, I actually think the problem is the question, rather than the answers. The question basically invites to one-line link-only answers, and is unlikely to yield any high quality answers that stand the test of time. I flagged the question. Maybe it should be closed, if not removed. Welcome grmbl - sorry your first experience here was a rough one. Wasn't your fault, but please don't blame Ghanima either.